# bug in laplace_like pymc2 when called with an array

Tags: pymc

Hello PyMC developers,

There appears to be a bug in the `laplace_like` function. 
It now returns:

```
return flib.gamma(np.abs(x-mu), 1, tau) - np.log(2)
```

But when `x` is an array (which it really always is), it should return

```
N = 1
if hasattr(x, "__len__"): N = x.__len__()
return flib.gamma(np.abs(x-mu), 1, tau) - N * np.log(2)
```

Easy test case:

```
import pymc
print -pymc.distributions.laplace_like(array([8]), 10, 1)
print -pymc.distributions.laplace_like(array([9]), 10, 1)
# likelihood of values 8 and 9 together
print -pymc.distributions.laplace_like(array([8]), 10, 1) -pymc.distributions.laplace_like(array([9]), 10, 1)   
# should give the same answer, but doesn't without the suggested fix    
print -pymc.distributions.laplace_like(array([8,9]), 10, 1)
```

This is also confirmed by comparison with the `laplace.nnlf` of `scipy.stats`

```
print laplace.nnlf((10,1),array([8,9]))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed, and the fix will be available in an upcoming big fix release (2.3.1)